# Arccos(x) > Arccos(x^2)

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve this inequality?

$$\arccos(x) \gt \arccos(x^2)$$

I've brushed up on arccos and it's basically the inverse function of the cosine and returns a degree value(or radians). Also, the domain of this function is -1, 1 and the range from 0 to pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\cos$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,\pi]$, so $\arccos$ is strictly decreasing on $[-1,1]$. Hence $\arccos(x)>\arccos(x^2)$ is equivalent to $x<x^2$.

Comment: why equivalent? With the fact that $\arccos$ is decreasing haven't we only the implication $\arccos x>\arccos(x^2) \implies x<x^2$, meaning that the set of solutions of $\arccos x>\arccos(x^2)$ is contained in the set of solutions of $x<x^2$ and we must check the other inclusion $x\in[−1,0) \implies \arccos x>\arccos(x^2)$ as well? Or maybe it is because $p \implies q$ is equivalent to $\neg q \implies \neq p$ and so $ \arccos x > \arccos (x^2) \iff x<x^2$? Thank you.

Comment: @sabakusousou The fact that it is $x^2$ has nothing to do with it, you would have $\arccos(x)<\arccos(y)$ equivalent to $x>y$ regardless because $\arccos$ is a strictly decreasing function.

Answer (score 0):

As the function $\arccos$ is monotonous decreasing,

$$\arccos(a)<\arccos(b)\implies a>b.$$

The given equation turns to
$$x<x^2$$
$$0<x(x-1),$$
$$x<0\lor x>1.$$